# Why do I get a ClassCastException when using Long instead of Integer?

Tags: java, filesystems, classcastexception

Basically trying out the following snippet I get a ClassCastException:

```
public static void main (String []args)     
{
    Path path = Paths.get((System.getProperty("user.home")), "Desktop","usnumbers.txt");
    try {       
    Integer size = (Integer)Files.getAttribute(path, "basic:size", NOFOLLOW_LINKS);
    System.out.println("Size: " + size.toString());
    } catch (IOException e) {
    System.err.println(e);
    }
}
}
```

It gets fixed once I change the keyword `Integer` with `Long`. I checked the documentation for `Files.getAttribute(...)` and it returns an Object not a Long. Furthermore, always in the same page, while explaining the usage of this method they are actually using an Integer keyword for casting the Object. [Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#getAttribute%28java.nio.file.Path,%20java.lang.String,%20java.nio.file.LinkOption...%29) is the link of the official oracle documentation explaining it.
Directly from the same link the method usage:

> Usage Example: Suppose we require the user ID of the file owner on a
>   system that supports a "unix" view:
>
> ```
> Path path = ...
> int uid = (Integer)Files.getAttribute(path, "unix:uid");
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Files.getAttribute` actual return type depends on attribute, so for "unix:uid" it returns `Integer` but for "basic:size" it returns `Long`. And you cannot cast Long to Integer and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

Try instead

```
Long size = (Long) Files.getAttribute(path, "basic:size", NOFOLLOW_LINKS);
System.out.println("Size: " + size);
```

You cannot use casting to convert types of references in Java.  This means that while you can cast `long` to `int` you cannot cast `Long` to `Integer`.

Answer (score 0):

The typecast fails because the attribute value returned is not an `Integer`.

The names and types of the attributes returned by `getAttribute(...)` are specified in the javadocs for the respective [`AttributeView`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/attribute/AttributeView.html) classes.  In this case, the javadoc for [`BasicFileAttributeView`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/attribute/BasicFileAttributeView.html) states that `size` is a `Long` not an `Integer`.

(And that makes sense, because the size of a file can be greater than `Integer.MAX_VALUE`.)

---

Lesson: don't just read the examples.  You need to read and understand the rest of the documentation as well.